# How to access localhost database from anywhere in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xampp, localhost

I have developed an android application which uses localhost xampp database. This server is running on my laptop and android application in running on my phone.

I can access database in my phone only when both (laptop and phone) are connected to same network (i am using same wifi for both device).

But i installed this android application in my friends phone(he is connected to different network/he is using his mobile data).But he is not able to access the database ,application giving toast message something like "java.connection error....."

How can i make my application should runs and access localhost database anywhere(which are connected to different network)?

Comment: host your database online?

Comment: Hi , Now just i want to test my application. there is no another way other than the hosting database online. for testing i need to host my database ?

Comment: If you want to test it on a different network, then yes you need to host it, there are multiple free hosting services.

Comment: `application which uses localhost xampp database.` A localhost database runs on the same device as your application. I think you use localhost wrong as every device is its own localhost. Also your Android phone.

Comment: Your friend should use the internet/public ip of your router. And on your router go to settings and forward the used port to your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I hosted my database and php files to online database hosting platform.
Now I can use my android application anywhere.